# Azure, creating a new virtual machine, it needs to allow chose the NetworkInterface

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

As creating a new Virtual Machine in Azure, sure on Resource Manager mode, It allows to configure new/existing plenty of parameters:

- Storage account
- Virtual Network
- Public IP Address
- Network security group
- Diagnostic Storage Account
- and so on ...

But not the Network Interface, creating then a random one with a name like MyVMname666 or any other 3 digits random number

Just: **WHY?**

Why not allow the user to configure it manually, or chose between existing

I can raise a new environment with all perfect defined resource names, except the Network interface ;-(

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerShell and\or Cli to achieve that, but this is not the place to raise this question. there's the [feedback portal](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback) for ideas like that.

As for the PowerShell, [here's the way to do that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-ps-create).